# How to setup Codeception with remote code coverage?

Tags: php, code-coverage, remote-server, codeception

- I have two repo on my machine

  1. API
  2. Codeception repo that tests API

In API repo I have added codeception+c3

```
"require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "2.*",
    "codeception/c3": "2.*",
```

I've also included c3.php inside index.php, but when trying to test it with --coverage I have this error

[PHPUnit_Framework_Exception]
  file_get_contents(http://local.api.codeception.com/c3/report/clear): fai
  led to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Is there *ANY* online example of remote codecoverage with Codeception?

Comment: - Ok, I wasn't lazy so I did a small repo with API and codeception tests for API
- Really don't know how to setup YML the right way

https://github.com/Horki/remotecoverage

Comment: have you tried to display the error which happens in c3? there is a constant you can set with "define('C3_CODECOVERAGE_ERROR_LOG_FILE', '/path/to/c3_error.log');" before including c3.php (@see https://github.com/Codeception/c3#setup) Within the file you should see the error why there is a 500 result.

Comment: A similar error and issue that might help: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was a configuration nightmare, but I've fixed it

[Here](https://github.com/Horki/remotecoverage) is example

Answer (score 2):

Here's my configuration for remote codecoverage with Codeception ([Project on GitHub](https://github.com/sky003/silex-user)).

---

## Steps for running up remote codecoverage collection

**1. Make sure that xdebug installed and enabled.**

**2. Configure codeception.**

File `codeception.yml` ([GitHub](https://github.com/sky003/silex-user/blob/d9cd17e3f7895d05c984b2ba1deea99902f4fbdd/codeception.yml#L14-L20)):

```
coverage:
  enabled: true
  c3_url: 'http://%SERVICE_HOST%/index-test.php/'
  include:
  - web/*
  - config/*
  - src/*
```

**3. Enable coverage for the suits you need.**

File `acceptance.suite.yml` ([GitHub](https://github.com/sky003/silex-user/blob/d9cd17e3f7895d05c984b2ba1deea99902f4fbdd/tests/acceptance.suite.yml#L8-L9)):

```
coverage:
  remote: true
```

*In my example its enabled only for acceptance tests.*

**4. Include `c3.php` file in your application bootstrap.**

Application bootstrap file `index-test.php` ([GitHub](https://github.com/sky003/silex-user/blob/d9cd17e3f7895d05c984b2ba1deea99902f4fbdd/web/index-test.php#L11-L12)):

```
// Start the remote code coverage collection.
require_once __DIR__.'/../c3.php';

// autoloader, application running and etc
// ...
```

**5. Run coverage.**

```
$ vendor/bin/codecept run --coverage --coverage-html
```

By default you can find your reports in `tests/_output` directory.

---

## Possible issues

**1. Output directory not writable (`tests/_output`).**

```
$ chmod 777 tests/_output
```

**2. Remote codecoverage not printed in console.**

It should not be printed. From documentation:

> ```
> coverage:
>   remote: true
> ```
>
> In this case remote Code Coverage results won’t be merged with local ones, if this option is enabled. Merging is possible only in case a remote and local files have the same path. But in case of running tests on a remote server we are not sure of it.

**3. Some other error.**

Try to [enable debug](https://github.com/Codeception/c3#debug). If debug enabled, you can get your report or clear it.

```
curl -o codecoverage.tar "http://localhost:8080/index-test.php/c3/report/html"
```

---

## End

Sometimes it's not a trivial task. So I hope this will help!